# MongoDB push to array with predefined index

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

How do I add an item to Mongoose, if I want to push it to an item of the array?
I want to push it to the document with predefined _id, to the 'productList' array with predefined 'id', to the 'items' array.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5ba94316a48a4c828788bcc9"),
"productList" : [
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "items" : [ 
            {
                "id" : 1,
                "name" : "FLOSS 500",
            }
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I thought that it should be something like this, but it did not work:

```
Products.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.body._id, productList: {id: req.body.id}}, {$push: {'items': req.body.product}})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this with positional operator `$`. For search by nested array property use dot-separated syntax:

```
Products.findOneAndUpdate({ 
    _id: req.body._id, 
    'productList.id': req.body.id 
}, { $push: { 'productList.$.items': req.body.product } });
```

Full example:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const Products = mongoose.model('Test', new Schema({
    productList: []
}));

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/myapp");

let item = new Products({
    "_id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5ba94316a48a4c828788bcc9"),
    "productList": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "items": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "FLOSS 500",
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
});

Products.deleteMany({}).then(() => {
    return Products.create(item);
}).then(() => {
    return Products.findOneAndUpdate({
        _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5ba94316a48a4c828788bcc9"),
        'productList.id': 1
    }, {
        $push: {
            'productList.$.items': {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "FLOSS 600",
            }
        }
    });
}).then(() => {
    return Products.find({
        _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5ba94316a48a4c828788bcc9"),
        'productList.id': 1
    });
}).then(data => {
    console.log(data);

    if (data) {
        console.log(data[0].productList);
        /* [{"id":1,"items":[{"id":1,"name":"FLOSS 500"},{"id":2,"name":"FLOSS 600"}]}] */
    }
}).catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
});
```

Comment: This did not work out. I might think that my approach to the query is wrong. 
DO I understand correct, that I can find document by _id and get another field like 'productList' in return, where then I will continue searching for other nested documents? Or It is better to refactor Mongoose Schemas and separate all nested arrays?

Comment: For search by nested array property use dot-separated syntax `'productList.id': req.body.id`. I updated my answer. It works for me.

Comment: Thank you! That worked, but I also had to make a nested Schema for Items array